# icacls broken in brackets

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, icacls

This is actually working but not in the format I prefer. The code below will achieve what I want. Makes a folder in any writable standard User Profile (I am aware it wont work in some system profiles like Default etc.) that some software needs and also gives it relevant permission.

```
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" 
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd"
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
```

This seems a bit over the top though. I am wanting to just have the one loop through the user folders and then use brackets to list the commands, saving a user loop for every function. However when I try the below, it doesn't even make the folders. If I debug using command line it stops at "everyone" was unexpected at this time. I'm not sure why? Any advice be welcome, thanks.

```
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do (
mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" 
mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd"
icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WMI to access only normal users profiles too:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIc Path Win32_UserProfile Where (Special!='True') Get LocalPath"'
    ) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Pause>Nul
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
For %%A In (Folder1 Folder1_Ltd) Do (If Not Exist "%*\AppData\Local\%%A\" (
        MD "%*\AppData\Local\%%A")
    ICACLS "%*\AppData\Local\%%A" /T /C /Q /grant:r Everyone:(OI^)(CI^)F /inheritance:e)
```

Comment: Wow now that is cool love asking stuff on here so much knowledge. Thanks to everyone will try all these ASAP. :)

Comment: All answers excellent and workable! I tick this one because it added the ability to only use user profiles (not system) which is added bonus, next & very tidy. Thanks ALL!!!

Comment: Put the Echo part as a new last line, perhaps adding `&&Set "_=T" ` after `/inheritance:e` but before the closing parenthesis. The new last line reading `If "%_%"=="T" Echo Permissions Applied to Computer Successfully`

Comment: Hey spot on! Will try that ...just remembered too, need to be able to do this for XP. I just tried that WMIC in a XP vm and seems it doesnt like that code, I have XP permissions to play with just no sure how to identify actual user profiles over system ones? Any tips? :/00))

Answer (score 4):

You've to escape all the closing parentheses inside the (code block) to not being interpreted as the end of the block.

```
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do (
    mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" 
    mkdir "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd"
    icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" /T /C /grant(:r^) "Everyone":(OI^)(CI^)(F^) /inheritance:e
    icacls "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd" /T /C /grant(:r^) "Everyone":(OI^)(CI^)(F^) /inheritance:e
)
pause
```

**Edit** as [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) suggested using a subroutine is an alternative (albeit using an editor to insert the `^` escapes is no big deal)

```
@Echo off
for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do Call :Sub "%%~fA"
pause
Goto :Eof
:Sub
mkdir "%~f1\AppData\Local\Folder1" 
mkdir "%~f1\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd"
icacls "%~f1\AppData\Local\Folder1" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
icacls "%~f1\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd" /T /C /grant(:r) "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(F) /inheritance:e
```

Comment: How about calling a subroutine instead? It seems like that would be less tedious and error prone.

Comment: @eryksun Ack, appended this alternative.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks :) just away from pc at moment so will try later and Mark as answered.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative could be to remove unneeded parenthesis and quote required ones

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do (
        for %%F in ("%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd") do (
            mkdir "%%~fF"
            icacls "%%~fF" /T /C /grant:r "Everyone":"(OI)(CI)(F)" /inheritance:e
        )
    )
```

If you want to keep the parenthesis in the `grant` switch, then you can

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%A in ("C:\Users\*") do (
        for %%F in ("%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1" "%%~fA\AppData\Local\Folder1_Ltd") do (
            mkdir "%%~fF"
            icacls "%%~fF" /T /C "/grant(:r)" "Everyone":"(OI)(CI)(F)" /inheritance:e
        )
    )
```

**note**: Both cases tested on windows 10. I can not test at this moment if the `icacls` hability to deal with quoted arguments (in the `/grant` case) is present in previous OS versions.

**note2**: Tested without problems (well, `/inheritance` switch did not exist) with the Windows 2003 server SP2 version of the `icacls.exe` (the first version published). As pointed by eryksun, the additional quotes are removed by the CRT.

Comment: In Windows 10, icacls.exe links with the private Windows CRT msvcrt.dll and uses its `wmain` entry point. I wouldn't expect this basic design to have changed from older versions, so I would wager that this also works in Windows 7, though I haven't tested to be sure. The CRT should strip out the quotes around `"%%~fF"`, `"/grant(:r)"`, `"Everyone"`, and `"(OI)(CI)(F)"` when parsing the command line into the `argv` array.

Comment: @eryksun, Thank you, this is what I think, but the executable could also use the [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and implement its own parser over the command line, leaving out or just as an alternative to `argc / argv`  and the full or partial behaviour could be changed between versions. At this moment I can not debug anything except the w10 executable, that is the reason for the note, I'm not sure.

Comment: Like every Windows program, icacls.exe does call `GetCommandLine` and parse the command line, but it's using Microsoft's CRT for this, which has [known behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx). I'll try to remember to check the Windows 7 version later, if you don't get to it first.

Comment: @eryksun, just for curiosity, debug `cmd.exe` and see `_main` function, checking how `argv` is not referenced (or I don't see where), while arguments are handled in `Init` function via `GetCommandLine`. In windows, being developed by several teams, the behaviour present in one program should not be considered as the *standard*, nor assume that a *known behaviour* is a standarized behaviour. The more I see, the less I trust but things became much more interesting.

Comment: I know cmd.exe uses custom command line parsing. It's a shell, and an old one that was developed for OS/2 in the mid 80s as an extension of DOS COMMAND.COM. And of course cmd.exe isn't the only program with custom command line parsing, and I didn't mean to imply that there was a "standard". I meant only that the CRT has documented rules for parsing the command line into arguments. You can break on `icacls!wmain` and then use `ba` to set a hardware breakpoint whenever it reads `argv[1]`. You'll see that icacls.exe does use the CRT's `argv` array.

Comment: @eryksun, Not tested with the rest of the versions, but both versions, the first one published (W 2003 SP2), as well as the last (W 10.0.15063), have the same behaviour, the one you have pointed. Thank you.